# How can I display a map on x-y axes of a space-time cube in R

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I work on animal movement analysis. I could generate a space-altitude cube for bird migration through Egypt.

I want to display the map of Egypt below, so that I see where do birds fly high and where they rest.
I have used the following code:

```
    library(leaflet)
    library(rgl)
    
    
    eamEgypt2011 <- read.csv('HUJ MPIO White Stork E-Obs Autumn 11_clean.csv')

    #Check columns of the dataframe
    names(eamEgypt2011)
    
    
    
    # create coloring order for bird individuals in the dataframe
    colors <- c('green', 'red', 'purple', 'black', 'white', 'yellow', 'gray', 'brown')
    pal2 <- colorFactor(colors, eamEgypt2011$individual.local.identifier)
    
    #Plot 3d plot (cube) to display bird altitude across space
    with(storkAutumn11, plot3d(location.long, location.lat, height.above.ellipsoid, type = "p",
                               col = pal2(individual.local.identifier)))
    rglwidget()
```

This code is working and giveس this outcome:  http://rpubs.com/KhaledElnoby/locatiionAltCubeCiconiaCicAutumnMig11

But, I want to display a map on the latitude-longitude axes, like this photo:
Example of what I want the plot to look like:

[image: Example of what I want to create like]

This is the output of R command

```
> library(leaflet)
> library(rgl)
> 
> 
> eamEgypt2011 <- read.csv('HUJ MPIO White Stork E-Obs Autumn 11_clean.csv')
> 
> names(eamEgypt2011)
 [1] "event.id"                                      "visible"                                      
 [3] "timestamp"                                     "location.long"                                
 [5] "location.lat"                                  "bar.barometric.pressure"                      
 [7] "data.decoding.software"                        "eobs.acceleration.axes"                       
 [9] "eobs.acceleration.sampling.frequency.per.axis" "eobs.accelerations.raw"                       
[11] "eobs.activity"                                 "eobs.activity.samples"                        
[13] "eobs.battery.voltage"                          "eobs.fix.battery.voltage"                     
[15] "eobs.horizontal.accuracy.estimate"             "eobs.key.bin.checksum"                        
[17] "eobs.speed.accuracy.estimate"                  "eobs.start.timestamp"                         
[19] "eobs.status"                                   "eobs.temperature"                             
[21] "eobs.type.of.fix"                              "eobs.used.time.to.get.fix"                    
[23] "gps.dop"                                       "gps.satellite.count"                          
[25] "ground.speed"                                  "heading"                                      
[27] "height.above.ellipsoid"                        "import.marked.outlier"                        
[29] "mag.magnetic.field.raw.x"                      "mag.magnetic.field.raw.y"                     
[31] "mag.magnetic.field.raw.z"                      "manually.marked.outlier"                      
[33] "manually.marked.valid"                         "quaternion.raw.w"                             
[35] "quaternion.raw.x"                              "quaternion.raw.y"                             
[37] "quaternion.raw.z"                              "sensor.type"                                  
[39] "individual.taxon.canonical.name"               "tag.local.identifier"                         
[41] "individual.local.identifier"                   "study.name"                                   
[43] "month"                                        
> 
> 
> # coloring for individuals
> colors <- c('green', 'red', 'purple', 'black', 'white', 'yellow', 'gray', 'brown')
> pal2 <- colorFactor(colors, eamEgypt2011$individual.local.identifier)
> 
> with(storkAutumn11, plot3d(location.long, location.lat, height.above.ellipsoid, type = "p",
+                            col = pal2(individual.local.identifier)))
> rglwidget()
```

Comment: What was the problem with your code? Without access to example data, we can't run your code to see what error occurs. It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include a [mcve]; in particular, adding the output of the R command `dput(eamEgypt2011)` would help

Comment: I have edited it. I hope it works now. Excuse me, this is my first question ever here :)

Answer (score 0):

`rgl` doesn't have any functions to produce the map; you'll have to find another way to do that.  You can use `par3d("bbox")` to find the bounds in each coordinate: it will give `c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax)`.  You'll want to somehow create a PNG file containing the map corresponding to `c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`.  Then

```
show2d("z-", filename = "map.png")
```

will display the map on the cube at the lowest value of z.  Check that you've got the right orientation for your plot by plotting some known locations.

The other way to do it, if you have R code to produce the map, is to run

```
show2d({par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)); plotmap()}, "z-")
```

as in the `?show2d` example.